# Python - psql prompt for password even if it got it

Tags: python, postgresql, pysftp

I'm working on a small code, which have to:

- Connect with SFTP
- execute command on PostgreSQL (password protected)

I am willing to use password as a plain text.

For the moment my code is:

```
import pysftp

command = "... some SQL command"

sftp= pysftp.Connection('server_name', username='username', password='password')
sftp.execute("export PGPASSWORD='password_to_psql'")
sftp.execute("psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d {} -U {} -W -c "{}"").format(database_name, user_name, command)
sftp.close()
```

I thought it was good idea, but when i type proper command in terminal, shell prompts for password (but is not required, when i 'enter', everything is executed.

Does anyone knows how can i 'disable' prompts, which are not required?

Comment: Cant you use SSH?

Comment: Use the lower case `-w` option in instead of the upper case `-W`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` has a `--no-password` option, which can also be specified as `-w`.

It looks like you might have misspelled `-w` as `-W`, which has the opposite effect.